# How to find out magnetic field strength using a Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I use the compass API in Windows Phone 7 to discover the local magnetic field strength?

Answer (score 2):

The reading of the magnetometer is a property, [CompassReading.Magnetometer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.compassreading.magnetometerreading%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). CompassReading is an ISensorReading, use Compass.Start and .Stop to begin and end acquisition of CompassReadings.